# Microsoft Active Directory SSO to docker container

Tags: docker, nginx, azure-ad-msal, spark-java

I have a web application running in a docker container. I need to let only the users authenticated with Microsoft SSO (only the users in my AzureAD tenant). The web application is written in Spark Java and trying to change the existing basic authentication to Azure with MSAL4j is proving to be time consuming and difficult.

Is there a way to authenticate all users with SSO externally to the container without having to change my application?

I saw an Azure NGINX solution on NGINX site but it seemed to not have a free version. Anything I can use out of the box or develop?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to authenticate all users with SSO externally to the container without having to change your application. You would need to change your application code and add the Azure Authentication manually.

Comment: I'm willing to change the application but would be great if I don't have to do too much. main reason is my app is an old spark java application and I keep running into errors trying to integrate MSAL. Idea is if I can use an available (say nodejs) container that deals with authentication, my java webapp can simply talk to that container and receive access keys etc. Basicall check with the node app if the user is authenticated.

Comment: Follow these steps in this documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-nodejs-webapp-msal

After you successfully signing to the application, store the token in localStorage. After that from the spark java web app access the localStorage and get your token.

Comment: Sounds promising. I have been reading on this a bit. If my authentication is meant for my Java Web App, the tokens should work as long as I can get it to my java web app. perhaps through a REST call to the node app? thinking about using the same across droplets.